# Java - Using timer to countdown until app closure

Tags: java, timer, countdown, shutdown

How can I use a Timer to count down from X to zero and increment the jProgressBar I have in my form?

The plan is, the program starts up checking if some needed files are installed, if they're not, the corresponding method tries to install them. If that fails, the method tells the calling method so. If these codes have been detected, the user gets notified that the program can't install the files and the program will get shut down with the notice "Please make sure you have started the program with administrative (uac) or root (sudo) rights.".

I'd like to use a timer to count down like I would in Visual Basic.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Take a look at the Timer object in java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

If you show some code or clarify your question bit better I can offer you better help but from what I digested you want to update your jProgressBar on some time interval well easy option is to create another thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
  public void run()
  {
    // Here you can use Timer or Thread sleep 1s up to X seconds
    // and on each iteration increment your jProgressBar.
    // TODO: Your code...

    return; // To kill the thread
  }
});

t.start();
```

Comment: Ok, let me clarify.

If the program detects the error,  it shall shut down.
But, I'd like to give the user some time to realize what's actually happening, so they don't go ahead wondering what's wrong and then just uninstalling the application because they don't understand what went wrong.

So to do that, I'd to use a timer or something similar to slowly increment the progress bar, two-4 steps a time, so the user has time to see there's something wrong.

Once the progress bar reaches its 100% the program closes.

I'm coming from VB, and in VB I'd use a timer to sort something like that out --

Comment: -- Like telling the timer to increment the progress bar 5 times every second, or so.
So the progress bar fills up five units every second so the program shuts down after 20 seconds.